# Updating the object with a new "map"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

It passes a list from map the checkbox to the view. In the lead, I view the mark  or not and now send new valueto the controller. How can I now update UserConfig whit new Value and  Iso that I can use new value on the project.

```
     @PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @ModelAttribute("userConfig") UserConfig userConfig) {
}



@Component
public class UserConfig {

    private Map<String, Boolean> isEnableMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Boolean> getIsEnableMap() {
        return isEnableMap;
    }


    public UserConfig() {
        isEnableMap.put(UserConfig.EnableProcess.TIME_UPDATE.getName(), false);
        isEnableMap.put(UserConfig.EnableProcess.SUM.getName(), false);

    }

... geter and setr ...
```

Part of my view

```
<label th:each="item : ${userConfig.isEnableMap}">
            <input type="checkbox" th:text="${item.key}" th:field="*{userConfig.isEnableMap['__${item.key}__']}"/>
        </label>
```